# how to combine two video and one audio via ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

i have an empty video "empty.mp4" and the main video "Video.wmv",
total length of both in addition equal to the audio "voice.wav".
i want to combine these videos and one voice in a single command because if i want to do that in two command, It takes twice as long.

Comment: Share your current set of commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i got that there is a single command to do both:

ffmpeg -i empty.mp4 -i Video.wmv -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" total.mp4

Comment: Where is the `voice.wav` in this command?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It does not take twice as long.

Next: `ffmpeg` can't concatenate two videos of different format without reencoding - it would result in an invalid output file, as most file formats don't allow different encodings in the same file.

So you have two approaches:

- either make both videos the same encoding and format, then you can use a concat file to do merging and A-V combining in one go
- or you can accept the reencoding on combine

Comment: Ok, if It does not take twice as long but i don't want to do the first option, how to do the second one, consider i want to do combination in one command.